# Does ${\rm Iso}(M\times N)={\rm Iso}(M)\times {\rm Iso}(N)$ hold for product metrics?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I know that ${\rm Iso} (M\times N)={\rm Iso}(M)\times {\rm Iso}(N)$ is not generally correct where $M$ and $N$ are smooth Riemannian manifolds; but

> Does ${\rm Iso} (M\times N)={\rm Iso}(M)\times {\rm Iso}(N)$ hold for product metrics?

what about warp-product metrics?

Comment: What do you mean by "for product metrics"? $M$ and $N$ should both be non-trivial Riemannian products of non-flat factors?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802676/killing-fields-on-product-metrics/1802908#1802908) seems relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Example:** $M=N=\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric.  Then $\operatorname{Isom}\mathbb{E}^2$ is a 3-dimensional Lie group, so obviously cannot be the Cartesian square of $\operatorname{Isom}\mathbb{E}^1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What can be say in compact case?

Comment: For example, see the link given by @AnthonyCarapetis